# classe active with @html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem to set the classes active with a specific color:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Fr", "Index")| @Html.ActionLink("Eng", "Index")
```

I tried using a helpers but it does not work.

Comment: Paste the full html code. Did you got css class="active" in the tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned below is the code making use of `ViewContext.RouteData`, also **make sure you are applying the `class="active"` on the `<li>` tag and not the `<a>` tag**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Contact" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if  this helped

Comment: still not working when i load the page no active still in i tried $("#filtre li a").click(function() {
  
 $("#filtre li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  
  return false;
  
 });   it worked but all my hyperlinks don t work

Comment: Ok can you create a Fiddle perhaps replicating your issue, it will help you as well.